# How do I store a yaml-rust enum into an instance of a struct?

Tags: rust, yaml

I'm trying to define a struct which has the `Yaml` type from [yaml-rust](https://github.com/chyh1990/yaml-rust) but it doesn't work. What data type should I use in the struct in this case?

```
extern crate yaml_rust;

use yaml_rust::{Yaml, YamlLoader};

struct Book {
    doc: Yaml,
}

fn main() {
    let s = "
foo:
    - list1
    - list2
";
    let docs = YamlLoader::load_from_str(s).unwrap();
    let doc = &docs[0];
    let _book = Book { doc: doc };
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:29
   |
17 |     let _book = Book { doc: doc };
   |                             ^^^ expected enum `yaml_rust::Yaml`, found reference
   |
   = note: expected type `yaml_rust::Yaml`
              found type `&yaml_rust::Yaml`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-read the error message:

```
expected type `yaml_rust::Yaml`
   found type `&yaml_rust::Yaml`
```

You don't have an instance of `Yaml`; you have *a reference* to an instance. Go back and review [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book), specifically the chapter on [references and borrowing](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html).

You can remove the value from the `docs` vector and pass it into your struct:

```
let mut docs = YamlLoader::load_from_str(s).unwrap();
let doc = docs.swap_remove(0);
let _book = Book { doc };
```